# Ubuntu 13.04 RAOP to Airport Express 2nd Generation doesn't work, how do I debug and get it working?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, apple, streaming

I have never had any luck with RAOP or Stream2Ip from Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 to my airport express 2nd generation.

In pulseaudio the airplay device either discovered by RAOP in paprefs or connected to by stream2ip appears and is selectable. However, when I start to play audio from VLC or Rhythmbox the players just sit there. The play button is "pressed" and the pause icon appears but the track doesn't start playing it just 'sits there'. No audio at all. If I change the output back to local speakers then the track starts playing.

It's frustrating to say the least, no one else seems to report this issue.

How can I debug what is going awry?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we do not have an Airport Express 2nd generation to test and debug this here. In case the old RAOP protocol is still recognized and supported by this device we may however be successful in streaming audio.

- With my old 1st generation Airport Express I was able to reproduce the behaviour of your player stopping playback after I added a wrong port to the IP of the device.
- In newer Airport Express devices it was possible to change the port the device listens to from default 5000 to any other port. That is why stream2ip >= 0.3.4 supports streaming via a port different to default 5000 (as was in 1st generation devices). You can do so by adding this port to the IP of the device:

  ```
  192.168.xxx.xxx:<port>
  ```

  [image]

Let me therefore suggest you find the port of your device (best from the setup programm run from Windows or MacOS) and try if adding this port to the IP line resolves the issue.

We can not however provide a solution for devices where the stream is set up to be password protected and hence needs encryption (this encryption is not open source).

We also can not support the newer RAOP2 protocol used in newer AirPlay devices as it still is not available for pulseaudio.

Comment: I thought pulseaudio-raop2 provided airtunes 2 compatibility?

Comment: yeah, there is some effort for a [pulseaudio-raop2](http://gitorious.net/~teuf/pulseaudio/pulseaudio-raop2) module but it seemed to have been discontinued in 2010. At present it is not yet integrated with the pulseaudio suite. I have not been able to test if it's working at all because sadly I do not have access to a RAOP2 device. Did you try it?

Comment: not yet, the documentaton in the git is rather light.